# Load instances from server after an action event (click) :Ajax, ruby, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ajax

I'm new to ruby and I am trying to create a small calendar application.

As to avoid loading all the events related to a user within the calendar before displaying them, I would like to load only the events of a single week.

Thus, I have so far manage to load only the current week of event and display them into my calendar (the calendar and the algorithm to display a list of events per day are all render using javascript), by using:

```
var week_events = []

<% @user.events.where('end_time >= ? AND start_time <= ?', Time.zone.now.beginning_of_week, Time.zone.now.end_of_week).each do |event|%>
      week_events.push([event])
<% end %>

var sorted_events = sort_events() //sort them per day and create a matrix for display
display_events_into_calendar(sorted_events)
```

My issue is then to be able to click on a button, which trigger the action to display the next week, and load the events related to that week. I am thus not able to update my list of events.

I have been reading about Ajax as it seems the right solution in order to make request from the server using javascript and jQuery.

https://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Unfortunately, it seems that I am confuse on how I should do it, is anyone could point me to the steps I should proceed to implement this feature ?

Update:

Thanks to @user3309314, I have looked into this pagination process made with Ajax. I have followed the post and thus created two new actions for my EventsController that now looks like this:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  @add_day = 0

  def load_next_week_events
    @add_day += 7
    now = Time.zone.now.beginning_of_week
    @loaded_events = @user.events.where('end_time >= ? AND start_time <= ?', now + @add_day*86400, now + (@add_day + 7) *86400)
  end

  def load_previous_week_events
    @add_day -= 7
    now = Time.zone.now.beginning_of_week
    @loaded_events = @user.events.where('end_time >= ? AND start_time <= ?', now + @add_day*86400, now + (@add_day + 7) *86400)
  end
end
```

I then added the routes inside my routes.rb as follow:

```
resources :events do
  put :load_next_week_events, :on => :collection
  put :load_previous_week_events, :on => :collection
end
```

and finally inside my _calendar.erb I added a jQuery action on my button to handle the click event as follow:

```
$(".right_arrow_calendar").click(function(){

  <% link_to "Load Next Week Events", {:controller => :events, :action => :load_next_week_events}, {:method => :get}%>

  var week_events = [];
  <% @loaded_events.each do |event|%>
    week_events.push([event]);
  <% end %>
});
```

Am I on the right track ? Anyway, this code still doesn't work, is it normal that my @loaded_events doesn't update yet ?

Comment: The exact answer can be quite lagre but maybe [this](http://jameshuynh.com/2016/01/28/ajax-pagination-on-rails-and-kaminari/) will lead you to some solution

Comment: Thanks @user3309314 for your comment! I have updated my post